# nftables how to temporarily allow a port(s) for an application

Tags: firewall, nftables

I am using **Warpinator** on my android phone to transfer files between my linux machines and my mobile phone.

The application uses ports for `42001` for initial connection, and `42000` for data transfer. I believe it uses TCP.

I am using nftables as my firewall, I have recently switched from firewalld. I have not been able to completely grasp the nftables.

I would like to temporarily allow these two ports `42000,42001` on my pc before starting application and after I am done, I would like to close these ports.

I want my existing rules to continue, add temporarily these rules, and them remove them if possible all with a bash/nft script.

Is it possible.

I appreciate any insight directions.

I have following simple default configuration in my `/etc/nftables.conf`

```
#!/usr/bin/nft -f
# vim:set ts=2 sw=2 et:

# IPv4/IPv6 Simple & Safe firewall ruleset.
# More examples in /usr/share/nftables/ and /usr/share/doc/nftables/examples/.

table inet filter
delete table inet filter
table inet filter {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter
    policy drop

    ct state invalid drop comment "early drop of invalid connections"
    ct state {established, related} accept comment "allow tracked connections"
    iifname lo accept comment "allow from loopback"
    ip protocol icmp accept comment "allow icmp"
    meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept comment "allow icmp v6"
    tcp dport ssh accept comment "allow sshd"
    pkttype host limit rate 5/second counter reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited
    counter
  }
  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority filter
    policy drop
  }
}
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this scenario is configure a chain for your temporary access:

In the below, the 'table' is "filter" (based on your example) and I'm using 'warpinator' as the identifier for these rules. (e.g. the table name doesn't actually matter, and I always found it horribly confusing to use 'reserved words' that way)

```
# Create a new chain and counter for this purpose. 
create chain inet filter warpinator
add counter inet filter warpinator

# add a rule to the chain 
add rule inet filter warpinator tcp dport { 42000, 42001 } log prefix "WARPINATOR: " counter name "warpinator" accept 

# insert a 'jump' condition to your input chain to inspect traffic
add rule inet filter input jump warpinator
```

This will enable inbound traffic from *any* source to these ports.

You might want to restrict that a bit more aggressively with something like:

```
add rule inet filter warpinator tcp dport { 42000, 42001 } ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 ....
```

which will limit it to address on that address range (192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255) - pick your 'home' network range maybe?

Save this as an nft script (in /etc/nftables maybe?) and then you can either:

- include it in your `main.nft` with an `include` line.
- run it adhoc with `nft -f <script>`

Because your 'nft' config includes `delete table inet filter` you can just reload it to remove the rule again. `nft -f <main policy>`

Alternatively you can leave the chain defined (in main.nft), and enable with:

```
add rule inet filter input jump warpinator
```

when you need it.

You can delete rules from policies if you like, but it's not as simple as you need a 'rule ID'.

E.g. run:

```
nft -a list ruleset
```

Look for your 'handle ID' for the 'jump' rule, and then delete it via the handle number. So I think just reloading your 'baseline' to turn off the port is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> The application uses ports for 42001 for initial connection, and 42000
> for data transfer. I believe it uses TCP.
>
> I would like to temporarily allow these two ports 42000,42001 on my pc
> before starting application and after I am done, I would like to close
> these ports.

Temporarily allowing ports is not possible to be done automatically, the only way to do it is by manually adding and removing specific rules as needed but might soon become boring.

A standard solution to this problem is to create restrictive rules that are based on stateful filtering.

Since port `42000` is used for data transfer this means it must be allowed only for `established` connections and as such it's not harmful to have the rule enabled all the time because port `42000` will be closed for new connections.

Only port `42001` is to be considered problematic and the solution to this is to apply it only to `new` connections and only to local subnet which is safe enough to do.

Example:

First create custom chains for `established` and `new` connections:

```
nft add chain inet filter established_in {
    comment "Established input traffic"
}
nft add chain inet filter new_in {
    comment "New input traffic"
}
```

Next step is to associate `related` and `new` traffic with those chains:

```
nft add rule filter input ct state established goto established_in
nft add rule filter input ct state new goto new_in
```

This will make `established` traffic be filtered by `established_in` chain and `new` traffic with `new_in` chain.
These chains are "added" to `input` chain which will redirect filtering to `established_in` and `new_in` chains based on state.

Next we add rules to those chains that allow `Warpinator` connection, you only need to update `saddr` address below to your local subnet so that only devices on your local network are allowed.
Alternatively you can restrict it to your android IP address!

```
add rule filter new_in ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 tcp dport 42001 accept
add rule filter established_in ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 tcp dport 42000 accept
```

Next step is to add all other `input` rules which you already have to allow for `established` and `new` connections to those chains.

These are (according to your sample):

```
iifname lo accept comment "allow from loopback"
ip protocol icmp accept comment "allow icmp"
meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept comment "allow icmp v6"
tcp dport ssh accept comment "allow sshd"
pkttype host limit rate 5/second counter reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited counter
```

When done adding those rules to custom chains, final step is to block everything else in those chains, so we add default block rules:

```
nft add rule filter established_in drop
nft add rule filter new_in drop
```

Your other rules are then added to base `input` chain as well, these are:

```
ct state invalid drop comment "early drop of invalid connections"
iifname lo accept comment "allow from loopback"
ip protocol icmp accept comment "allow icmp"
meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept comment "allow icmp v6"
tcp dport ssh accept comment "allow sshd"
pkttype host limit rate 5/second counter reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited counter
```

Important to know is that `established` connections (handled by `established_in` chain) are handled separately, while `new` connections (handled by `new_in` chain) are also handled separately, everything else which is `related` and `invalid` traffic is handled by `input` chain which also redirects `established` and `new` connections to respective chains.

Benefit of this approach is that port `42000` will not be opened unless port `42001` is accessed first, which is accessible only to local network which is safe.